# ClassNotFoundException: javax.lang.model.element.Element

Tags: java, apache-axis, classnotfoundexception

I created a Webservice (Axis2) with Eclipse and deployed to a Glassfish Server.

Axis2-web runs fine, but when I request the WSDL of my service I just get an expcetion:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/lang/model/element/Element
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceWrapperGenerator.<init>(WebServiceWrapperGenerator.java:130)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp.process(WebServiceAp.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.lang.model.element.Element not found by com.sun.xml.bind [150]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 52 more
```

Usually a `NoClassDefFoundError` means a dependency is missing, but 'javax.lang.model.element.Element' is from the JRE ('rt.jar') so I have no clue what is wrong here.

**More Details:** Eclipse Juno, Glassfish 3.1.2, Axis2-1.6.2, Dynamic Web Project

Comment: Check your runtime classpath

Comment: @Chris Like I said. This class is from the JRE and this is of course in the classpath. I run glassfish via eclipse. Default JRE is JDK1.7_13 (there is no other). Even if I put rt.jar into WEB-INF/lib it will not work.